# How to make my ui-view in Angular responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, responsive-design

In Angular I have a nested ui-view with vertical tabs, which looks like this on desktop.

[image: vertical tabview dekstop]

on mobile, only the list should be visible with 100% width.

[image: mobile list view]

when clicked, the content should be displayed, like this.
[image: mobile ui-view]

My question is what is best practice to do this in Angular?
Currently I'm doing this with enquire.js, but this is far from optimal.
The code looks like this:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 480px)", {

match : function() {
    //FRANCHISE VIEW
    $( ".franchiseslide > a" ).click(function() {
        $(".franchiseselectlist").css('display','none');
        $(".franchisecontent").css('display', 'block');
        $(".franchisecontent").css('width', '100%');
        $(".viewback").css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

    $( ".viewback").click(function() {
        $(".franchiseselectlist").css('display','block');
        $(".franchisecontent").css('display', 'none');
        $(".viewback").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

},
```

Could I solve this with ui-router or ui-sref-active? Optimally, the content on mobile should slide in with an animation. What would be the best way to implement ngAnimate?

Comment: You could do it with CSS, surely? And just use ng-class and ng-click to handle swapping classes around which triggers CSS changes (and potentially animations?)

Comment: My advice would be to make use of angular material. It comes in with built in directives which makes responsive coding a cakewalk

Comment: This is absolutely nothing to do with Angular.js here — everything can be done with pure CSS and media queries. Angular.js is a Javascript framework, it knows nothing about responsiveness and layouts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways of making your application responsive.

One way is to use the browser agent string to determine the device type and redirect user to the appropriate view type. For example in angular you could re-direct the user to a different partial based on the browser type.

The alternative is to use css media queries and display the same page differently depending on available real-estate on the device. There are existing javascript libraries such as bootstrap that you can incorporate in your Angularjs application to handle this if you don't want to write your own media queries.